# Can we simulate the execution of TFX command (azure devops)? something like parameter -Whatif (powershell)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

We need to simulate the following tfx command (Azure Devops):

```
tfx build tasks upload --task-path C:/folderX
```

I know that in powershell we have the possibility of using -WhatIf as a parameter. But I think it is native to powershell commands. TFX does not apply.

powershell -Whatif parameter reference:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-don-t-fear-hitting-enter-with-whatif/ba-p/353579

Would someone have an idea how we could simulate tfx command?

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose? As you've surmised, `-WhatIf` only applies to powershell commands and only those that explicitly support it

Comment: Hi Samuel D, any update on this ticket, could explain more clearly about your issue?